# Reminders too slow in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm making a windows phone app that uses a lot of reminders and I decided to start with a test of the performance of ScheduledActionService methods (Add, Remove, Replace, Find) to see what would be the fastest/easiest way to do it.

I started testing and it took the app 1.5 seconds to remove 14 reminders and then create new 14 reminders. It took the same time with find/replace. That is a lot slower than I expected. This test was performed on an HTC 8X. Then I did the same thing on a Samsung Omnia 7 and it was a lot faster. Replacing of the 14 reminders took about 200ms. Remove/add was about 100ms slower. Both tests were without debugging and I did them several times to see if it was something random and it was not.

Here's the code for the tests:

```
    public void RefreshReminders() {
        var st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        st.Start();

        foreach (var reminder in ScheduledActionService.GetActions<Reminder>()) {
            ScheduledActionService.Remove(reminder.Name);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            string reminderName = i.ToString();

            Reminder reminder = new Reminder(reminderName);
            reminder.Title = "Reminder";
            reminder.Content = string.Format("Some data: {0}", i);
            reminder.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2000);
            reminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;

            ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
        }

        st.Stop();
        LogToIS("Reminders replaced (remove/add) in: " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        st.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            string reminderName = i.ToString();

            Reminder reminder = (Reminder)ScheduledActionService.Find(reminderName);
            reminder.Content = string.Format("Some data: {0}", i + 5);
            reminder.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2000);

            ScheduledActionService.Replace(reminder);
        }
        st.Stop();
        LogToIS("Reminders replaced (find/replace) in: " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
```

LogToIS just writes a string to a file in the isolated storage.

Any ideas why this would run slower on a much faster phone?

**Edit:** The results on the HTC 8X are the same, no matter if the app is a WP7.1 app or a WP8 app.

Comment: The final xap is it a WP7.1 or WP8 app? Perhaps because WP7.1 need some emulation on WP8 devices, the app runs slow.

Comment: @Mike Didn't think about that, thanks. I'll test it as a WP8 app now and update the question with the results.

Comment: @Mike I tested it and it's the same. :/

Comment: Yes they are slow. You have to change app flow and refresh them one at a time. Faced same issue ;(